# After ajax call, control's visibility is not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

After my ajax call as shown below, I'm trying to refresh div(few text box controls are in div) and making country dropdownlist invisible.
divPersonalDetails is getting refresh successfully. But country dropdownlist still visible. Please let me know how to make it invisible.

```
<div class="span3">
   @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CountryId, Model.CountryList, "--Please Select Country--", new { id = "ddlCountryId" })
   @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CountryId, new { id = "hdnCountryId" })
   <div style="margin-top:4px">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CountryId)</div>
</div>

 $("#btnSearch").click(function (e) {
    var idnumber = $("#txtDocumentNo").val();
    var url = '@Url.Content("~/")' + "signature/GetDetails";
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'Get',
            data: $('#frmRegistration').serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                var url2 = '@Url.Content("~/")' + "signature/GetDetails";
                $('#divPersonalDetails').load(url2 + ' #divPersonalDetails');
                $("#ddlCountryId").hide();
            }
        });
        return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element is probably not loaded when you hide it, [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) has a callback for when the elements are loaded

```
$('#divPersonalDetails').load(url2 + ' #divPersonalDetails', function() {
     $("#ddlCountryId").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change your JS click function like below and then try.

Note: **I have changed the 1st line only in your JS**

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnSearch'(function (e) {
var idnumber = $("#txtDocumentNo").val();
var url = '@Url.Content("~/")' + "signature/GetDetails";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'Get',
        data: $('#frmRegistration').serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            var url2 = '@Url.Content("~/")' + "signature/GetDetails";
            $('#divPersonalDetails').load(url2 + ' #divPersonalDetails');
            $("#ddlCountryId").hide();
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```